# Odoo 13 API how to save null search results as a string

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

I am using the Odoo 13 api as such.

```
  wanted_ids= models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
                                        'res.partner', 'search_read',
                                        [[['name', '=',False]]],
                                            )
    print(wanted_ids)
```

as expected nothing is returned.

```
[]
```

What I want instead of null

```
['Nothing found']
```

I am not sure how to approach this. I have tried to raise exceptions but this does not save to the `wanted_ids` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not wanted_ids:
    wanted_ids = ['Nothing found']
```

This is pure Python, I think so